# Merge one file to other file in groups

Tags: python, pandas

In `Python` and `Pandas`, I have one dataframe for 2018 which looks like this:

```
Date    Stock_id    Stock_value
02/01/2018  1   4
03/01/2018  1   2
05/01/2018  1   7
01/01/2018  2   6
02/01/2018  2   9
03/01/2018  2   4
04/01/2018  2   6
```

and a dataframe with one column which has all the 2018 dates like the following:

```
Date
01/01/2018
02/01/2018
03/01/2018
04/01/2018
05/01/2018
06/01/2018
etc
```

I want to merge these to get my first dataframe with full dates for 2018 **for each stock** and with NAs wherever they were not any data.

Basically, I want to have for each stock a row for each date of 2018 (where the rows which do not have any data should filled in with NAs).

Thus, I want to have the following as an output for the sample above:

```
Date    Stock_id    Stock_value
01/01/2018  1   NA
02/01/2018  1   4
03/01/2018  1   2
04/01/2018  1   NA
05/01/2018  1   7
01/01/2018  2   6
02/01/2018  2   9
03/01/2018  2   4
04/01/2018  2   6
05/01/2018  2   NA
```

How can I do this?

I tested

```
data = data_1.merge(data_2, on='Date' , how='outer')
```

and

```
data = data_1.merge(data_2, on='Date' , how='right')
```

but I still got the original dataframe with no new dates added but only with some rows which had everywhere NAs added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for all combinations of values with `Stock_id` and merge with `left join`:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], dayfirst=True)

from  itertools import product

c = ['Stock_id','Date']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df1['Stock_id'].unique(), df2['Date'])), columns=c)
print (df)
    Stock_id       Date
0          1 2018-01-01
1          1 2018-01-02
2          1 2018-01-03
3          1 2018-01-04
4          1 2018-01-05
5          1 2018-01-06
6          2 2018-01-01
7          2 2018-01-02
8          2 2018-01-03
9          2 2018-01-04
10         2 2018-01-05
11         2 2018-01-06
```

and

```
df = df[['Date','Stock_id']].merge(df1, how='left')
#if necessary specify both columns
#df = df[['Date','Stock_id']].merge(df1, how='left', on=['Date','Stock_id'])
print (df)
         Date  Stock_id  Stock_value
0  2018-01-01         1          NaN
1  2018-01-02         1          4.0
2  2018-01-03         1          2.0
3  2018-01-04         1          NaN
4  2018-01-05         1          7.0
5  2018-01-06         1          NaN
6  2018-01-01         2          6.0
7  2018-01-02         2          9.0
8  2018-01-03         2          4.0
9  2018-01-04         2          6.0
10 2018-01-05         2          NaN
11 2018-01-06         2          NaN
```

---

Another idea, but should be slow in large data:

```
df = (df1.groupby('Stock_id')[['Date','Stock_value']]
         .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').reindex(df2['Date']))
         .reset_index())
print (df)
    Stock_id       Date  Stock_value
0          1 2018-01-01          NaN
1          1 2018-01-02          4.0
2          1 2018-01-03          2.0
3          1 2018-01-04          NaN
4          1 2018-01-05          7.0
5          1 2018-01-06          NaN
6          2 2018-01-01          6.0
7          2 2018-01-02          9.0
8          2 2018-01-03          4.0
9          2 2018-01-04          6.0
10         2 2018-01-05          NaN
11         2 2018-01-06          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, why when I did `data = data_1.merge(data_2, on='Date , how='right')` I was not getting basically the same dataframe as before but simply with some rows which has NAs at all their columns?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - because need merge by 2 columns, not only Date - my `df = df.merge(df1, how='left')` is same like `df = df.merge(df1, how='left', on=['Date','Stock_id'])`

Comment: Yes, I agreee but the second dataframe which has only the dates does not have any Stock_id column.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - exactly there is reason use `product` like in my answer.

Comment: Ok good. By the way, is there not any simpler solution to this? I am quite (negatively) surprised again with Pandas that there is not a simpler solution to this rather simple problem.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - pandas is not database, so it seems not.

Comment: Cool, no worries and thank you for your help in any case (upvote). However, the more I learn about Pandas the more I realise that it has quite many imperfections. I expected operations like this (and other ones from other posts of mine here at which you helped me again) to have a simpler solution.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - No problem, also added another solution with `reindex`, but not sure if fast. I guess not.

Comment: itertools is a better solution here. :) +1